# Migrating inactive users to aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, flask-login, flask-security

Currently, I'm using flask security to manage the Auth in my web app. I want to migrate the entire Auth to AWS Cognito. I saw the migration documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/). But nowhere it says how to migrate users who are set as inactive.

What I need to do is to migrate all users even the inactive ones but the inactive one should be set as inactive in cognito too. is there any way to set users as inactive during the migration?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided does mention Batch User Upload. Basically it involves exporting your user database as .csv and then importing into cognito. Keep in mind that you cannot transfer passwords into cognito userpool. User will have to create his password when he logs in for the first time.

Comment: I've updated the question. What I need is to set the inactive users as inactive even while migration.

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable the user?

Comment: Yes. Disable the user while migrating.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to write your own logic to iterate through all the "inactive" users in your previous database and disable them using 
AdminDisableUser https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDisableUser.html